# Show text in 3d pyqtgraph, using GLTextItem class of GLGraphicsItem python

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

The below code is for creating a GLTextItem from GLGraphicsItem but when the object is called it gives the error

> "Error while drawing item <gl_classes.GLTextItem object at 0x000001D903BB34C0>."

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from pyqtgraph.opengl.GLGraphicsItem import GLGraphicsItem
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

class GLTextItem(GLGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, X=None, Y=None, Z=None, text=None):
        GLGraphicsItem.__init__(self)

        self.text = text
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.Z = Z

    def setGLViewWidget(self, GLViewWidget):
        self.GLViewWidget = GLViewWidget

    def setText(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.update()

    def setX(self, X):
        self.X = X
        self.update()

    def setY(self, Y):
        self.Y = Y
        self.update()

    def setZ(self, Z):
        self.Z = Z
        self.update()

    def setPosition(self, X, Y, Z):
        self.X = X+0.25
        self.Z = Z+0.6
        self.Y = Y
        #self.text = '('+str(X)[:4]+', ' + str(Y)[:4]+', '+str(Z)[:4]+')'
        self.text = '(1,2,3)'
        self.update()

    def paint(self):
        self.GLViewWidget.qglColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.GLViewWidget.renderText(self.X, self.Y, self.Z, self.text)
```